# Right align navbar buttons

Tags: css

[This is my navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIaP5.png)I have used https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_store&stacked=h for help.But I am not able to make the buttons float to the right of the navbar even though I have copied the same code.
This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Auctions{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            /* Remove the navbar's default rounded borders and increase the bottom margin */ 
            .navbar {
              margin-bottom: 50px;
              border-radius: 0;
            }
</style>
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                <a  href="{% url 'index' %}">Active Listings</a>
            </li>
            <li >
                <a  href="{% url 'create' %}">Create Listings</a>
            </li>
            <li >
                <a  href="{% url 'categories' %}">Categories</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>{{ user.username }}</li>
            <li><a  href="{% url 'logout' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Log Out</a></li>
            <li ><a  href="{% url 'mywatchlist' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>My watchlist</a></li>
            
            {% else %}
            <li >
                <a  href="{% url 'login' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Log In</a>
            </li>
            <li >
                <a  href="{% url 'register' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Register</a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done here is taked Official code from [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_store&stacked=h) and just added your vars and your content. You can see final code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}Auctions{% endblock %}</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Active Listings</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'create' %}">Create Listings</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'categories' %}">Categories</a></li>
      </ul>
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{ user.username }}</a></li>
           <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Log Out</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'mywatchlist' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> My watchlist</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                      <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                         <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Register</a></li>
                                     {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


</body>
</html>
```

**Notice :** As @Tobias S saied in his answer it might be adding the fake tag What solved the problem. Thanks @Tobias S.

Comment: woah thanks! I just copy pasted your code and it works perfectly..I'm not sure what I did wrong sigh

Comment: The same like in my answer, he added fake a-tags ;)

Comment: @TobiasS Not sure but at I will update my answer beacasue I admire everyone Effort;

Comment: @TobiasS I have updated Answer; have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

The css styles you are using are only valid for list elements, that got an a-tag inside. So this is the dirty fix:

```
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>{{ user.username }}</li>
```

should be

```
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>{{ user.username }}</a></li>
```

Otherwise add a new class to the list elements without a-tag and add the css:

```
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
color: #9d9d9d;
```

Comment: I did this but it isn't fixing the issue of the buttons after categories to float to the right